# Checking if a number is even without built-in functions

Tags: python

Given an integer value as input, write a Python script that checks if the number is even or not. The script should print 'True' if it's an even number, and 'False' if it's not. Don't use any built-in Python functions, only simple mathematical operations.

I tried a lot but I just can't find the solution.
This was the best I could arrive:

```
def is_even(n):
    
    if n % 2 == 1:
        return False
    else: 
        return True
```

It looks like I can't use module %.
I even tried ChatGPT without success.

Comment: 1) “It looks like I can’t use …” from what source? This is the idiomatic approach.  2) ChatGPT? Not surprised.  3) What about using a bit mask, if using a modulo isn’t an option?

Comment: Why do you think that you can't use modulo?

Comment: This should work.  Of course you have to **call** this function to get a result.  Are you actually calling it?  Defining a function without calling it will do nothing.

Answer (score 1):

This is very vague...

> Don't use any built-in Python functions, only simple mathematical operations.

then

> It looks like I can't use module %.

What are the specifics?

My attempt at the limited information of basic math would be + - / *
And taking into account your use of `if` and `else` I assume `while` is allowed.

And therefor a solution being something like:

```
def is_even(n):
    # Assumes n > 0 (positive int)
    while n >= 2:
        n -= 2
    if n == 0:
        return True
    return False
```

If you want to handle non positive you can just add:

```
if n < 0:
    n = -1*n
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are not allowed to use `%`, you can just implement it: `a % b = a - (a//b) * b`

Answer (score 0):

the function looks fine, i can only guess that you provide a non integer input?

```py
def even(v):
  v=int(v)
  return v % 2 == 0

print(even(2)) # prints true
```

Comment: “I can only guess …” *isn’t* an answer.  This would be better placed as a comment.